# Que significa este mensaje: Trying to get property of non object?

Tags: php

Estaba intentando añadir una clase a todas mis imagenes y estube jugando un poco añadiendo codigos. Y cuando entre a la parte de personalizar mi tema me di con la sorpresa de ese mensaje.

Tengo 3 de ellos:

> [15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice: Trying to get property
>   'post_title' of non-object in
>   /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 825
>
> [15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of
>   non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 825
>
> [15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of
>   non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 829

¿saben que significa exactamente? ¿Es peligroso?

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
/* linea 825 */
$original_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $original_object->post_title, $original_object->ID );
if ( '' === $original_title ) {
    /* translators: %d: ID of a post */
    /* linea 829 */
    $original_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $original_object->ID );
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, dice que estas tratando de acceder a la propiedad de un elemento que no es un objeto. Para obtener una solución al problema puedes subir el código.

Comment: Significa que esa propiedad no existe. Muchas veces se debe a que tratas de acceder a un objeto que esta a null, aunque no es el único motivo...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No podemos saber que pasa si no vemos tu codigo.

Comment: Hola disculpen, ya subí el codigo

Comment: Esto es php sobre wordpress?

Comment: Lo que os comparto, lo estoy sacando del file de mi host. Tanto el mensaje de error de la carpeta ERROR y el codigo de la carpeta NAV-MENU

Comment: que es $original_object? el problema esta sobre esa variable

Comment: Al parecer esto responderia que es:

$original_object = get_post( $args['menu-item-object-id'] );

   $original_parent = (int) $original_object->post_parent;

   $original_title  = $original_object->post_title;

  } elseif ( 'post_type_archive' == $args['menu-item-type'] ) {
   $original_object = get_post_type_object( $args['menu-item-object'] );
   if ( $original_object ) {
    $original_title = $original_object->labels->archives;
   }
  }

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias a todos, ya encontre el error!
Dias anteriores habia tumbado mi web y active el modo debug de wordpress, y me habia olvidado desactivarlo. Ahora lo he desactivado y el mensaje ya no aparece :D
espero eso signifique que todo este bien